# Change clustered index without touching primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

we have an existing database where we would like to change the clustered index to a unique, monotonically increasing field (as it should have been from the start), but we don't want to change the primary key because there is data referencing this primary key.

We have added a new column `SequentialId` and populated it with data, to serve as our new clustered index.

But how do we change the clustered index? If possible, we would like to either replace the existing clustered index OR add `SequentialId` to the current index as the first column.

How do we go about this? It seems we cannot change the clustered index without dropping the primary key (which we can't do).

Comment: Remember that your clustered index key is used by all NON clustered indexes on that table to refer back to a row, therefore you should make evry effort to make it as narrow as possible.  The general rule of thumb I use is to use an INT if possible, a GUID where not.

Comment: Why do you have to use sequentialid instead? That seems like a strange requirement. I could see if you were using a guid how that could make sense but sequential values seems a bit strange.

Comment: @MJH using a guid as a clustered index is not a very good idea. It will hit 99.9999% fragmentation with just a few hundred rows, unless you populate it with sequentialid which rather defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Sean Lange You can use sequential IDs

Comment: @MJH sure you can avoid fragmentation using sequential but what is the point? You have a really wide column for a clustered index that is not more than an identity taking up a lot more space.

Comment: How does using sequential IDs defeat the purpose of using a GUID?

Comment: An IDENTITY(1,1) will be unique for a table, a GUID will be unique everywhere.  If you are importing data from multiple systems into a single DB this is quite handy.

Comment: @MJH but you said sequential ID. That is NOT unique everywhere. It has all the downsides of an identity (easily guessable etc) and it a lot wider. Once you start using NEWID to populate the uniqueidentifier the fragmentation explodes. This has been written about many many times. Kimberly Tripp has about the best article on the topic here. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/

Comment: She lists some examples of GOOD clustered keys in there, and one of them is NEWSEQUENTIALID().

Comment: @MJH right. But that is NOT the same thing as NEWID. A sequentialid is NOT globally unique.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ALTER TABLE` command drop the `PRIMARY KEY` **constraint**, which is not the same as dropping the `CLUSTERED INDEX` that is enforcing the `PRIMARY KEY` contraint, and recreate with the additional columns

```
ALTER TABLE <Table_Name>
DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>

ALTER TABLE <Table_Name>
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> PRIMARY KEY (<Column1>,<Column2>)
```

Comment: Question quite clearly says 'we cannot change the primary key because there is data referencing this primary key'. Therefore what you have suggested is wrong.

Comment: Huh???? How can you say that dropping the primary key is not the same as dropping the primary key? That doesn't make sense. And since other tables reference this key those foreign keys would all have to be disabled before this would work.

Comment: I understood the question as the Clustered Index mentioned is enforcing the Primary Key constraint mentioned